# Парсинг Json на C#

Tags: c#, json

Прощу подсказать по возможности, как распарсить строку вида:

```
{"server_time":1520605826,"pairs":{"ltc_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"nmc_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"ppc_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"dash_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"doge_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"cam_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"cann_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"uro_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"opal_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"via_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"sdc_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"start_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"gsx_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"vtc_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"smbr_btc":{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2},"etco_btc":
...//
{"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2}}}
```

`server_time` вопросов нет.
Но вот `ltc_btc, nmc_btc` и т.д. жутко неохота прописывать в классе, так как их повторюсь очень много. Возможно ли как то распарсить на массивы и желательно, что бы `ltc_btc, nmc_btc` и т.д. переписывались в `string` к остальным параметрам:

```
"decimal_places":8,"min_price":0.00000001,"max_price":10000,"min_amount":0.0001,"min_total":0.0001,"hidden":0,"fee":0.2,"fee_buyer":0.2,"fee_seller":0.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хоть вам и лень все это искать (а на эту тему на самом стаке ооочень много ответов), помогу вам все же...

Для начала, очень советую данный ресурс: [тык](https://app.quicktype.io/). Также я буду в ответе использовать Json.net библиотеку.

Взглянем на структуру вашего JSON:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы видим, что в корне у нас есть некий `long` объект `server_time` и дальше идет некая коллекция `pairs`. В коллекции `pairs` мы видим неизвестное (динамичное) для нас имя некой подгруппы `ltc_btc`, внутри этой группы есть другие, интересующие нас объекты. Так, вроде бы разобрались, давайте создадим необходимую структуру данных и попробуем десериализовать JSON:

Создадим для начала простое, нашу категорию `pairs`:

```
public class Pair
    {
        [JsonProperty("decimal_places")]
        public long DecimalPlaces { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("min_price")]
        public double MinPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("max_price")]
        public long MaxPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("min_amount")]
        public double MinAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("min_total")]
        public double MinTotal { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hidden")]
        public long Hidden { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fee")]
        public double Fee { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fee_buyer")]
        public double FeeBuyer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fee_seller")]
        public double FeeSeller { get; set; }
    }
```

Здесь все просто, название класса `Pair` - ибо наша коллекция будет `Pairs` (множественное), один объект `Pair`. Далее каждое значение приведено к своему типу (long, double и др.), задавайте сразу верное значение!. Также можно заметить, что у каждого значения есть некий флаг `JsonProperty`, который указывает оригинальное имя объекта! Ведь не правильно в C# языке назвать переменную `fee_seller`, да и не красиво это. Ок, часть работы сделана.

Следующим шагом будет создание еще одного класса, который будет содержать в себе `server_time` и нашу коллекцию `pairs`, раз это корневой класс, давайте так и назовем его:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("server_time")]
    public long ServerTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pairs")]
    public Dictionary<string, Pair> Pairs { get; set; }
}
```

Здесь вроде все понятно, имена (как и в классе `Pair`), пометки и все остальное. Интересное тут заключается в коллекции `Pairs`, как можно видеть, это словарь (Dictionary). При десериализации, под каждый `ltc_btc`, `nmc_btc`, `opal_btc`... мы получим своварь, который в ключе (key) будет хранить название нужного раздела (`opal_btc` к примеру), а в значение (value) будут "внутренности", в виде класса `Pair`.

Ну чтож, раз структура у нас есть, осталось сделать десериализацию:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jstring);
```

Ну тут прям совсем просто, мы в `JSON` (которой будет задан тип RootObject) десериализуем данные из полученной заранее `string jstring` переменной.

Все, теперь можно вывести необходимые данные:

- Мы можем к примеру сделать поиск по ключу:

  ```
  var data = json.Pairs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ltc_btc");
  Console.WriteLine($"Key: {data.Key} {data.Value.MaxPrice}");
  ```
- А можем вывести все объекты сразу с помощью цикла:

  ```
  foreach (var pair in json.Pairs)
  {
      Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}, {pair.Value.MaxPrice}");
  }
  ```

Ну, надеюсь я вам помог. В дальнейшем, прошу вас не лениться и хотя бы немного попробуйте поискать информацию! Удачи!

Comment: Благодарю вас, за столь развернутый ответ, очень помогли.